# A question about *A new proof of a theorem of Narasimhan and Seshadri*

Tags: riemann-surfaces, connections

I am reading S. K. Donsaldson's paper *A new proof of a theorem of Narasimhan and Seshadri*. Now $M$ is a compact Riemann surface and $E$ is a holomorphic bundle over $M$ with a Hermitian metric. There is a statement (p.276) : for $g$ a self-adjoint complex gauge transformation $g=g^*$, $A$ a Hermitian metric 
\begin{equation}
 F(A)=F(g.A)\implies \partial\bar\partial(g^2)=-\{(\bar\partial g^2)g^{-1}\}\{(\bar\partial g^2)g^{-1}\}^*
\end{equation}
where $F$ is the curvature form.

I try to prove this.

Here I think a problem happens.

We have 
\begin{equation}
 g.A=A-(\bar\partial g)g^{-1}+((\bar\partial g)g^{-1})^*=A-\bar\partial gg^{-1}+g^{-1}\partial g
\end{equation}
and for a section $\sigma$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 F(g.A)\sigma=&(d_{g.A})(d_{g.A})\sigma\\
 =&(d_A-\bar\partial gg^{-1}+g^{-1}\partial g)(d_A-\bar\partial gg^{-1}+g^{-1}\partial g)\sigma
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and just consider the second order derivative of $g$ 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 F(g.A)\sigma=&F(A)\sigma+d_A(-\bar\partial g g^{-1}\sigma)+d_A(g^{-1}\partial g\sigma)+\cdots\\
 =&F(A)\sigma-\partial\bar\partial gg^{-1}\sigma-g^{-1}\bar\partial\partial g\sigma+\cdots
\end{split}
\end{equation}
so from $F(A)=F(g.A)$ we will get something like 
\begin{equation}
 \partial\bar\partial gg^{-1}-g^{-1}\bar\partial\partial g+\cdots=0
\end{equation}
but I think this is different from $\partial\bar\partial(g^2)=\cdots$, since in which the second derivatives are 
\begin{equation}
 \partial\bar\partial g g+g\partial\bar\partial g
\end{equation}
and the $\partial$ operator is always ahead of $\bar\partial$ operator. If $\partial\bar\partial g+\bar\partial\partial g=0$, then the problem is solved but I do not think this is naturally true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $\partial \bar\partial g + \bar\partial\partial g=0$. In fact $\partial \bar\partial + \bar\partial\partial$ is the zero operator. 
We have that $d= \partial + \bar\partial$ is the induced connection on $End(E)$. Then 
$$ d^2 = \partial^2 + \partial \bar\partial + \bar\partial\partial + \bar\partial^2 = \partial \bar\partial + \bar\partial\partial $$
is the curvature of the induced connection on $End(E)$, since $\partial^2 = \bar\partial^2 =0$ (by dimension). Then the result follows once we have $End(E)$ flat.

We have that the curvature of $E$ is a multiple of the identity automorphism by hypothesis, $F(A) = \mu 1$ in page 276. Computing the curvature of the induced connection on $E\otimes E^\ast \simeq End(E)$ we see that it vanishes.

Comment: I am not sure if it is naturally true but $d_Ad_A$ is the curvature of the connection and is not zero in general.

Comment: For sure. However the hypotheses imply that $End(E)$ is flat

Comment: I just included that in my answer.